# Error: TestTaskApplicationTests » IllegalState Could not find a valid Docker environment. Please see logs and check configuration

Tags: java, docker, testing

I want to add testcontainer in my tests

```
    public static final PostgreSQLContainer<?> postgresContainer = new PostgreSQLContainer<>("postgres:13")
            .withDatabaseName("TestTask_DB")
            .withUsername("root")
            .withPassword("root")
            .withExposedPorts(5432);

    static class Initializer implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {
        public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext configurableApplicationContext) {
            TestPropertyValues.of(
                    "spring.datasource.url=" + postgresContainer.getJdbcUrl(),
                    "spring.datasource.username=" + postgresContainer.getUsername(),
                    "spring.datasource.password=" + postgresContainer.getPassword()
            ).applyTo(configurableApplicationContext.getEnvironment());
        }
    }
```

When i start it from IDE - all ok. But if i use docker-compose up - it gives me an error. (mvn test is working)

my docker-compose file:

```
services:
  app:
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - db
      - testcontainer
    environment:
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:postgresql://db:54320/TestTask_DB
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: root
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD: root
    restart: on-failure
    command: bash -c "sleep 15 && java -jar /usr/app/TestTask-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"

  testcontainer:
    image: postgres:13
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: root
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: root
      POSTGRES_DB: TestTask_DB
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"

  db:
    image: postgres:13
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: root
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: root
      POSTGRES_DB: TestTask_DB
    ports:
      - "54320:5432"
```

ChatGPT cant help me :(
Help me please ...

Comment: org.testcontainers.dockerclient.DockerMachineClientProviderStrategy -- docker-machine executable was not found on PATH

It cant find docker inside my maven-container

Comment: Testcontainers are usually used for unit testing during build. Why do you want to start it in docker-compose? Sounds like a worng use case to me.